# Why luminescence peak can move to higher energies with increasing temperature?

Tags: optics, solid-state-physics, spectroscopy, electronic-band-theory

Can somebody explain me, why sometimes I see changes in position of luminescence maximum as temperature dependence in dielectric crystals? Is this is caused by band gap changes or maybe some exciton processes?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I think more specific information would be useful here, what crystals, what temperatures, what luminescent energies etc. Band-gap get smaller with increasing temperature.